# How to write placeholder in pdf using itext

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am using itext and converting html to pdf for that i am using this code

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.StringReader;

import javax.sql.rowset.spi.XmlWriter;

import com.itextpdf.text.Chunk;
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.PageSize;
import com.itextpdf.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker; 
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

public class HtmlToPDF2 {
  // itextpdf-5.4.1.jar  http://sourceforge.net/projects/itext/files/iText/
  public static void main(String ... args ) {
    try {
      Document document = new Document(PageSize.LETTER);
      PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("testpdf1.pdf"));
      document.open();

      HTMLWorker htmlWorker = new HTMLWorker(document);
      String firstName = "<name>" ;
      String sign = "<sign>";

      String str = "<html> " +
            "<body>" +
                "<form>" +
                    "<div><strong>Dear</strong>  "+firstName +",</div><br/>"+
                    "<div>"+
                        "<P> It is informed that you are selected in your interview<br/>"+
                        "   and please report on the <b>20 may</b> with your all original <br/>"+
                        "   document on our head office at jaipur.>"+
                    "   </P>"+
                "   </div><br/>"+
                "   <div>"+
                    "   <p>Yours sincierly </p><br/>"+sign+"</div>"+
            "   </form>"+
            "<body>"+
            "<html>";
      htmlWorker.parse(new StringReader(str));
      document.close();
      System.out.println("Done");
      }
    catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

but this will give me output

> [image]

desired output is

> [image]

and is it correct way to create placeholder .. or i need to do anything else to create placeholder ? if yes then please suggest me .

Comment: HTMLWorker was deprecated in favor of XML Worker. With XML Worker, you can create your own tags and add a special implementation to the tag factory. That could solve your problem...

Comment: I've got a filmed presentation here: http://itextpdf.com/summit.php#talk3 and some sample code here: http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/itextdoc/flatsite.html but the documentation is far from finished.

Answer (score 1):

< and > signs consider as html tags. Because of that it don't show in your pdf.

you can define firstName and sign as below..

```
public class HtmlToPDF2 {
public static void main(String ... args ) {
....
....
String firstName = "&lt;name&gt;" ;
String sign = "&lt;sign&gt;";
....
....
}
}
```